# Need help correcting my SQL for a crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm using the below code to export a crosstab query to excel.

I've tried `Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qry_Comparison_Bulk")` but I always get Error: Too few parameters. Expected 19. There are 19 parameters stored in that query. My next thought was to just recreate the SQL in VBA. Now I'm getting Error: Too many crosstab column headers (424). 424 is the total number of items in my db so I'm thinking that the filter isn't working appropriately.

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TRANSFORM Sum(tbl_Formulas.Input) AS SumOfInput " _
& "SELECT tbl_Formulas.BillType, tbl_Formulas.RawMaterial " _
& "FROM tbl_Formulas " _
& "WHERE (tbl_Formulas.BillType)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill1] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.BillType)='" & [Forms]! [frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill2] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.BillType)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill3] & "' AND (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" &[Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 1] & "' Or " _ 
& "(tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 2] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 3] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 4] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 5] & "' Or " _
& "(tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 6] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 7] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 8] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 9] & "' Or " _
& "(tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 10] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 11] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 12] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 13] & "' Or " _
& "(tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 14] & "' Or (tbl_Formulas.Item)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 15] & "' AND (tbl_Formulas.BP)='" & [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![BP] & "' " _
& "GROUP BY tbl_Formulas.BillType, tbl_Formulas.RawMaterial " _
& "PIVOT tbl_Formulas.Item;")
```

There are '" & ... & "'delimiters to avoid the use of parameters as the values for each of the fields are text.

Further, my form is set up with 15 text boxes for "Item", 3 text boxes for "BillType", and 1 text box for "BP"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your `qry_Comparison_Bulk` query references form controls like this `tbl_Formulas.BillType=[Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill1]`

And the query works when run from the Access query designer.  The problem is that when you try to use that named query with `OpenRecordset`, each of those controls is treated as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.

So supply the values ...

```vba
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_Comparison_Bulk")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

`prm.Name` will be what Access interprets to be the parameter name ... like `[Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill1]` ... so `Eval(prm.Name)` is equivalent to `Eval([Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill1])` ... and returns the value of that control ... which you then assign to `prm.Value`

Comment: You're welcome.  If it were me, I would also revise the query to use `IN()` instead of `[Field]=this OR [Field]=that OR [Field]= ...` and so on.  Something like this: `FROM tbl_Formulas AS f WHERE f.BillType IN ([Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill1], [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill2], [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![bill3])`

Comment: I can make that change. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off with your first approach: You just have to set the parameters in your query before getting the recordset:

```
Public Sub ProcessQuery()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qry_Comparison_Bulk")

    ' set parameters
    qdf.Parameters(1).value = [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 1]

    Set rs1 = qdf.OpenRecordset
End Sub
```